# How not to connect to disabled networks when no configured network is available

Tags: wpa-supplicant

How can I make `wpa_supplicant` **not** connect to expressly **disabled** open networks when no configured network is available? (How can I make it not connect to anything whatsoever?)

This happens when my card fails to find my home network. In this case, `wpa_supplicant` connects to any other available network, even disabled networks.

For example, my neighbour has an open network (SSID: `xfinitywifi`) with a strong signal. This network is expressly disabled in my `wpa_supplicant.conf`: (See this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80550/) also by me.)

```
network={
  ssid="xfinitywifi"
  key_mgmt=NONE
  disabled=1
  priority=0
}
```

This works most of the time. However, if my card happens not to find my home network, `wpa_supplicant` then just ignores `disabled=1` above, and connects to `xfinitywifi`.

This can be shown from `wpa_cli` output (reformatted):

```
> disconnect
OK
> list_networks
0   neighbour1           any        [DISABLED]
1   xfinitywifi          any        [DISABLED]
2   neighbour2           any
---CUT---
12  neighbour12          any
13  any                             [CURRENT]
>
> reconnect
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
<3>SME: Trying to authenticate with 06:1d:d3:4c:37:00 (SSID='xfinitywifi' freq=2447 MHz)
<3>Trying to associate with 06:1d:d3:4c:37:00 (SSID='xfinitywifi' freq=2447 MHz)
<3>Associated with 06:1d:d3:4c:37:00 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 06:1d:d3:4c:37:00 completed (reauth) [id=13 id_str=]
```

Notice that #13 (`any`) is the current network (`[CURRENT]`), which turns out to be #1, `xfinitywifi`, a **disabled** network (`[DISABLED]`).

Answer (score 1):

Disable the **default** network configuration in `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
network={
        key_mgmt=NONE
        disabled=1
}
```