# How to prevent wpa_supplicant from connecting to a network, while allowing other networks

Tags: linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80552/20526) I try to configure wpa_supplicant as follows:

```
network={
        ssid="known_to_be_bad"
        key_mgmt=NONE
        disabled=1
}
network={
        key_mgmt=NONE
        priority=-10
}
```

The idea is that the `known_to_be_bad` network is not to be used, but I still want wpa_supplicant to consider any other open network.

But with this configuration, it can still happen that wpa_supplicant connects to the bad networking, showing this upon `list_networks`:

```
110 known_to_be_bad any [DISABLED]
111     any [CURRENT]
```

Can I blacklist this ssid more reliably?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like `disabled` may not be universally supported. it's listed in the link below, but not in freeBSD's wpa_supplicant.conf(5).

however.. there's a couple possible issues with your config:

- your catch-all is `priority=-10`, but not having a priority will default to `priority=0`. since `0 > -10`, your first "bad" network will try to connect first.
- if `scan_ssid=1` and `ap_scan=2`, priority is ignored and will use the order in the config file (according to [example conf](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/external/bsd/wpa/dist/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf)). try moving your "bad" network to the end of the file.
- i haven't seen a negative priority used before, and have no idea if it could be an issue, but if nothing else, maybe try sliding your priorities to `>= 0`?

Comment: I tried the priority dance, but it did not work (just like for the poster of the other question).  Also, moving it past the default seems to make no sense: After all, I *do* want this section to match the network (and then be ignored).

Comment: moving the bad net past the default only makes sense if wpa_supplicant is ignoring the priority and reading the networks in beginning-to-end order, but if it stops matching the networks after finding one to connect to, then i can see why that wouldn't work for you. that said, the only other solutions that i've been able to find seems to be about disabling the default net. sorry. (edited because i accidentally hit enter)